# Jquery no error but not working

Tags: jquery, callback

I have this code right now that makes the  element slide to the middle when I click on it and then fadeOut's the . So far so good. But now my 2nd function, which is that I want my  to fadeIn again and THEN slide to the right.

I've got 2 problems:

fadeIn doesn't kick in and after that I can't slide back to the left again.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.sectiontitel', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('on');
        $(this).addClass('off');

        $(this).find('span').animate({
            'margin-right': '350px',
        },200,

            function(){
                $(this).closest('section').find('article').fadeOut(300);
            });

    });

    $(document).on('click', '.off', function(){ 
        $(this).removeClass('off');
        $(this).addClass('on');

        $(this).closest('section').find('article').fadeIn(300)

    },

        function(){
            $(this).find('span').animate({
                'margin-right':'2px',
            },300
            )
        });


});
```

jfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/go6dvpuc/

Edit: Sorry forgot the jfiddle

Comment: You're passing two handlers in your last call to `on("click")`. The second one will be ignored at best and cause problems at worst. Maybe you wanted to pass the second handler as a completion callback to `fadeIn()` instead?

Comment: Well... yes, but you're passing two functions to `on()` in your second call. Fixing your indentation would allow you to notice that more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several errors:

- `function` to animate `span` back is declared as `.on` forth argument, while it has to be second argument of `fadeIn` function.
- in mentioned function, `this` points to `article`, not to `section`, so `find('span')` would not find any elements.
- after clicking on `h2 class='sectiontitel'` it will have both `sectiontitel` and `off` classes, so clicking on it will trigger both handlers.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/go6dvpuc/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(document).on('click', '.on', function()
    { 
        $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off');
        $(this).find('span').animate
        (
            {
                'margin-right': '350px',
            },
            200,
            function()
            {
                $(this).closest('section').find('article').fadeOut(300);
            }
        );  
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.off', function()
    {
        $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on');
        var section = $(this).closest('section');
        var onFadeIn = function()
        {
            section.find('span').animate
            (
                {
                    'margin-right': '2px'
                },
                300
            )
        };
        section.find('article').fadeIn
        (
            300,
            function()
            {
                onFadeIn();
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues here:

1. You've added 2 click callbacks to the same element (classes `sectiontitel` and `off` are assigned simultaneously, so both callbacks fire at one point). So in your markup add default `on` class to the click target, like this:

   ```
   <h2 class="sectiontitel on">
   ```

   And your first callback should now bind to `on` class:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.on', function(){ ...
   ```
2. jQuery [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) has second parameter, which is called after animation is complete, so simply rewrite your second callback like this:

   ```
   $(document).on('click', '.off', function(){ 
       $(this).removeClass('off');
       $(this).addClass('on');
       var $switch = $(this);
       $(this).closest('section').find('article').fadeIn(300, function(){
           $switch.find('span').animate({
               'margin-right':'2px',
           },300);
       });
   });
   ```

   Note that I've remembered `$switch`, cause the value of `this` changes in inner scope. See working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/iluzyanin/go6dvpuc/1/).